# Series that sum to log(2)??

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

Hy,

I have trouble with series that should(by reliable solutions) sum to $\log(2)$, but I don´t understand how, because series for log(x) should be alternating and any formula from textbook or Wikipedia for series of logarithms doesn't fit in this equation. Series are following:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{2^{-k}}{k} $$

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I really can´t see how it sums to $\log2.$

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

For $|x|<1$,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}n=-\ln(1-x)=\ln\frac1{1-x}.$$
Take $x=1/2$ in this series.

Comment: Thanks! Could you just pleas tell me how did you get this series? They dont look like taylor series.

Comment: It is a Taylor (or Maclaurin) series. You can integrate $\sum_0^\infty x^n=1/(1-x)$ to get it.